# How to find the mean, median and quartiles, range, and IQR from a data set?

Tags: statistics

Here's the data set:

Tornadoes 2011: Here are the annual numbers of deaths from tornadoes in the United States from 1998 through 2011

130 94 40 40 555 54 35 38 67 81 125 21 45 544

a) mean
b) median and quartiles 
c) range and IQR

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend to not respond well (or at all) to questions like this that look like basic homework problems and which show no effort.  Please edit your post to indicate what you have tried and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a mean, you simply take the average of all the numbers.  You add them up and divide by the number of terms.

(130+94+40+40+555+54+35+38+67+81+125+21+45+544) / 14 = 133.5

To find the median, you sort the list then select the center term.  If there are two, you select both.

21 35 38 40 40 45 (54 67) 81 94 125 130 544 555

Quartiles are found by splitting the remaining lists.

21 34 (38 40) 40 45 (54 67) 81 94 (125 130) 544 555

Then you average everything in parentheses, so
Q1 = 39
Median = 60.5
Q3 = 127.5

The range is found by taking the difference between the highest and lowest numbers, so:

555 - 21 = 534

IQR is trickier.  You subtract Q1 from Q3.

127.5 - 39 = 88.5